# Why won't my alert work in one of my functions?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the `nameVerification()` function to throw the `alert()` message when the user hits `submit`.  For example, if the user enters something like `45` in the `name` field, I want that `alert` in `nameVerification()` function to be called.  Right now, when the user does type in a number in the `name` field, the `alert()` in the `formSubmission()` function is being called.

Side note: 
`formSubmission`function works perfectly.  In other words, if the user enters a number < 13 in the `age` field, the functions `alert()` gets called normally with no problems.  If the user enters a number > 13, it works, also, without a problem.  Just thought I'd let you guys know that too.

signUp.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Signup Form</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="signUp.js"></script>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="signUp.css">
<body>

<form class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" name="formHandler" id="handle">
        <div class="moveUsername">
            <label for="usr">Name:</label>
            <input type="field" class="form-control" id="nameVerify" placeholder="Username" required="required">    
        </div>

        <div class="ageMovement">
            <label for="usr" >Age (Must be 13 years or older to play):</label>
            <input type="field" class="form-control" id="ageVerify" name="ageChecker" placeholder="Age" required="required">
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="formSubmission()" onclick="nameVerification()">Submit</button>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

signUp.js

```
  function nameVerification() {
    var name = document.getElementById("nameVerify").value;

    if(typeof name !== 'string') {
        alert("That's not a name!");
    }   
}

function formSubmission() {
    var age = document.getElementById("ageVerify").value;

    if(age < 13) {
        alert("You're too young, you can't play the game");
    }   
}
```

Comment: why do you have 2 onclick attributes? you can compress them to one like this: `onclick="formSubmission();nameVerification()"`

Comment: Also, your 'name' variable will ALWAYS be of type string - so the conditional alert() call will never run even if nameVerification() gets executed. You should check against the empty string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your nameVerification function as follows:

function nameVerification() {
        var name = document.getElementById("nameVerify").value;

```
    if (name) {
        var num = parseInt(name) || -1;
        if (num >= 0 && num < 13) {
            alert("That's not a name!");
        }
    }
}
```

and change your onclick values in the html to be:

onclick="formSubmission();nameVerification()"

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you :D.  One thing though, may you please explain what the `-1` is for?   Thanks again :).

Comment: Sure. The first part of the check is to see if the value entered can be parsed to an Integer value, if it can't be parsed the -1 acts like an error check. If not a number, then return -1. There are other checks you can use like NaN in javascript and so forth, but this seemed easier. So if you get a -1 back, then you have text entered and not a number.

Answer (score 3):

`age` is also a `string` in this function:

```
function formSubmission() {
    var age = document.getElementById("ageVerify").value;

    if(age < 13) {
        alert("You're too young, you can't play the game");
    }   
}
```

If you want to do a numeric compare, you need to parse first:

```
function formSubmission() {
    var age = document.getElementById("ageVerify").value;

    if (age) {
       var ageInteger = parseInt(age, 10);

       if (ageInteger < 13) {
           alert("You're too young, you can't play the game");
       }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have two onclick attributes on the button

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="formSubmission()" onclick="nameVerification()">Submit</button>
```

You can only have one

Comment: Oh ok.  I used the logic where if it's the same submit button that could cause these errors, I might as well have to have two `onclick` attributes.

Comment: Unfortunately you can only have one. So nameVerification() is never actually getting called

Answer (score 1):

Your `typeof` test is failing because the value returned from a text input is always of type string.  You can test to see if a provided text value is numeric with the following function:

```
function isNumeric(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

The real answer, however, is that you'll need to improve your input validation tests to determine what you **want**, rather than test for all the things you **don't want**.  For example, testing for a numeric value as above would not work if someone entered "t@^!" in the field, which is likely not a value you would want in a name field.  This is where [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), and the [built-in validations from HTML](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/html5forms/)5 fields can help.

Answer (score 0):

it's because the javascript is not loaded yet.

Move:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="signUp.js"></script>
```

To just above the `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You should use parseInt:

```
var age = parseInt(document.getElementById("ageVerify").value);
```